# Country name not saving to table or showing in view rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have a simple app where you can upload recipes

I have just integrated the gem terrarum to give me all the countries of the world within my country model. I have a relationship where a recipe has_one country and a country belongs to recipe. I am using nested forms from ryan bates and have had no problem getting information to show from my ingredients model and preparation model. But i cannot get the country name to save in the table or show in the view (though this is caused by not saving to model)

Code is as follows

Form

```
<%= f.label :country_id, "Country Of Origin" %>
<%= f.collection_select(:country_id, Country.all, :id, :name, :prompt => 'Please select country') %>
```

View

```
<% @recipes.each do |r| %>
<tr>
<td><%= r.dish_name %></td>
<td><%= r.country.name %></td>
<td><%= r.difficulty %></td>
<td><%= r.preperation_time %></td>
<td><%= ingredient_names(r.ingredients) %></td>
<td><%= preperation_steps(r.preperations) %></td>
<td><%= image_tag r.avatar.url(:thumb)%></td>
</tr>
```

Helper

```
def preperation_steps(preperations)
if preperations
  preperation_array = preperations.map {|pre| pre.prep_steps}
  preperation_array.join("\n")
end
end

def country_name(country)
if country
  country_array = country.map {|c| c.country_name}
  country_array.join("\n")
end
end
end
```

I have included my preparation helper as this works, so surely my country_name helper mirrors this? or do i not need to put a helper in for this?

recipe controller

```
def new 

@recipes = current_user.recipes if current_user.recipes #show recipes if the user has any recipes
 @favourites = current_user.favourites

end
```

recipe model

```
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :country
  has_many :ingredients 
  has_many :preperations
  has_many :favourites

  attr_accessible :dish_name, :difficulty, :preperation_time, :ingredients_attributes, :preperations_attributes, :country_id, :avatar:preperations_attributes, :country_id, :avatar

  has_attached_file :avatar, :styles => {  :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "100x100>" } 

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :ingredients, :preperations

  scope :top_countries, order("country_of_origin DESC")
```

if anyone can help it would be much appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this code I see two mistakes:

1. `Recipe` should `belong_to :country`. Don't use `has_one` here. The foreign key `country_id` should be in the `recipes` table.
2. `@recipe.build_country` is not necessary. You already have a list of countries. You should only use `build_country` if you are planning to add a new country to the list of countries, which you are not in this case.

Also, you don't need `fields_for`. You can just do:

```
<%= f.label :country_id, "Country Of Origin" %>
<%= f.collection_select(:country_id, Country.all, :id, :name, :prompt => 'Please select country') %>
```

Comment: thanks for the pointers. guess there are different rules when a model is already pre populated? I have done as you said, but now when i view my add recipe form the field for country names is missing?

Comment: You don't need `<%= f.fields_for :country do |ff| %>` either. All you want is a dropdown to select a country, right?

Comment: so its no longer a nested attribute?, yes just a dropdown

Comment: Yes, you don't need a nested attribute in this case. You can just do `<%= f.collection_select(:country_id, Country.all, :id, :name, :prompt => 'Please select country') %>`.

Comment: thanks, so within my attr_accessible for my recipe model can I add country_id?

Comment: No. All you have to do is remove `:country` from `accepts_nested_attributes_for`. You should have a column `country_id` in your `recipes` table, so you don't need to accept nested attributes for that.

Comment: thanks very much, yes that makes sense..last question ( sorry, new to rails), im trying to figure out how i get the county name to display in the block, r.country outputs #<Country:0xad91ebc>

Comment: i just checked the entries in the recipe model and country_of_origin is nil? so its still not saving?

Comment: You only have to save the id of the country. Do you have a field `country_id`? If so, you don't need `country_of_origin`. To get the name of the country do `<%= r.country.name %>`.

Comment: r.country.name returns undefined method name, and when you say country_id, you  mean in the recipe model? and i should remove country_of_origin from the recipe model?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I guess you also have to `:country_id` to `attr_accessible`.

Comment: Ok will do that, thanks very much for your help, will let you know how it goes

Comment: Hi, apologies to ask again but I have updated my code in the question, is there anything you can see that looks incorrect?still getting undefined method name. bit stumped now

Comment: Well, you probably have some old recipe records that don't have a country associated with them yet. Try `<% if r.country %><%= r.country.name %><% end %>` in your view. Or delete the recipes that don't have a country: `DELETE FROM recipes WHERE country_id IS NULL`.

Comment: thats it, didnt even think about the old records and putting in a if statement.. Massive thanks :)

Comment: Glad it's working. Check out [this link](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html) for more info about associations.

Comment: Its nice to have a community that is willing to help us newbies out :)